Docker, Frankenphp, Laravel error could not find driver Connection: pgsql
I am suffering with a very strange and annoying problem... I am driving the situation crazy:
I have created a docker container that has the following configurations:
Dockerfile
# Dockerfile
FROM php:8.3-fpm

# PHP INI
COPY /docker/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    zip \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql pdo_pgsql mbstring pdo pgsql exif pcntl bcmath gd

# Install Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www

# Install Composer dependencies
RUN composer install --prefer-dist --no-progress --no-interaction --no-dev

# Expose port 9000
EXPOSE 9000

# Start Laravel Octane
CMD ["php", "artisan", "octane:start", "--server=frankenphp", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=9000"]


docker-compose.yml
services:
    frankenphp:
        image: dunglas/frankenphp
        container_name: frankenphp
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
            - "443:443"
        volumes:
            - .:/app
            - ./certs:/certs
            - ./docker/caddy/Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile
        networks:
            - app-network

    db:
        image: postgres:14-alpine
        container_name: db
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        volumes:
            - ~/apps/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
        networks:
            - app-network

    pgadmin:
        image: dpage/pgadmin4
        container_name: pgadmin
        restart: unless-stopped
        volumes:
            - pgadmin_data:/var/lib/pgadmin
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        environment:
            - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=email@email.com
            - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=password
        networks:
            - app-network

    php:
        build: .
        container_name: php
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www
        working_dir: /var/www
        networks:
            - app-network

    composer:
        image: composer:latest
        container_name: composer
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        working_dir: /app
        networks:
            - app-network
        entrypoint: [ "composer" ]

    redis:
        image: redis:6-alpine
        container_name: redis
        ports:
            - "6379:6379"
        command: redis-server --requirepass "password"
        networks:
            - app-network

    npm:
        image: node:latest
        container_name: npm
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        working_dir: /app
        networks:
            - app-network
        command: npm install

volumes:
    pgadmin_data:

networks:
    app-network:
        driver: bridge

.env
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=app
DB_USERNAME=app
DB_PASSWORD=password

I have created a database app as well as privileges for the user app
When I start:
docker compose up --build -d
then I run:
docker compose run --rm php php artisan migrate OR docker compose run --rm php php artisan migrate:fresh
Everything works and the tables are uploaded to the database.
But when I open the app I get the error:
could not find driver (Connection: pgsql, SQL: select * from "sessions" where "id" = YVQKOF5zkNoZv4yfC3A5MlcU64hYyD8gG9tv8O7o limit 1)
nothing is written in the sessions table and it gives an error in the driver. I can't figure out where the problem is... I'd be glad if someone has come across this to help me.
thanks in advance
I have even added an external php.ini file in which I have added:
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 20M
max_execution_time = 60
memory_limit = 256M
extension=php_pgsql.so


installs correctly everywhere:
docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql pdo_pgsql mbstring pdo pgsql geolocation pcntl bcmath gd
But things don't work out.

As a laravel developer, if you are encountering this issue on your Laravel App:
could not find driver (Connection: pgsql, SQL: select * from "sessions" where "id" = irm9IMFseLaF0DyyRzZUNbgkJeybu1UoT8cS7e9s limit 1)
Step 1: Put off your Local Server (Laragon, Xamp or Wamp or any other server)
Step 2: Navigate to your php.ini file
Do make sure you allow these  extensions on your php.ini file on your local server:
extension=pgsql
extension=pdo_pgsql

.env:
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=your_database
DB_USERNAME=your_username
DB_PASSWORD=your_password


You aren't using the php service for your app. Your ports are configured on the frankenphp service which you haven't added that extension to.
